# Ruby on Rails Update field of all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a bit of trouble and I'm not sure if it's even possible to do what I want.

I have a `user` model with a field called `points`. I also have a `matches` model.

I've been trying to use my `matches_controller` to update the `points` field of every `user` when a match gets updated (by a site admin). The goal is to add points if the user selected the correct score.

I'm not sure if I'm able to do this. I'm wondering am I incorrect trying to access the `user` model from the `matches_controller`? Because I want to update all fields when a `match` score is updated, I need to do it from the `matches_controller`

I've been going around in circles trying to solve this. Am I approaching it incorrectly?

Thanks for reading and hopefully helping.

Here's the relevant code

> matches_controller.rb

```
  def update      
    respond_to do |format|
      if @match.update(match_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @match, notice: 'Match was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @match }
      else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @match.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

    MatchPick.where(:matchID => params[:id]).update_all(result: match_params[:result], closed: match_params[:played], points: 0)
    MatchPick.where(:matchID => params[:id], :userPick => match_params[:result]).update_all(points: 3)
    update_user_points
  end

  def update_user_points
    @users = User.all
    @users.each do |user| 
      user.points = 4
      puts params
    end
  end
```

Comment: have you tried update_all? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class

Comment: You need to save object user after setting points attribute value. But its costly. Try update_all, as rderoldan1 said.

Comment: I was trying to use update_all but couldn't figure out how to just add a value to the existing points:  .update_all(points: += 3) would not work

Comment: Saving the object worked and was costly as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use update_all unless you're updating a field in all the records to the same value, which is not the case here.

How about this?

```
MatchPick.where(:matchID => params[:id], :userPick => match_params[:result]).each do |mp|
  mp.user.update_attribute(:points, mp.user.points + 4)
end
```

(this is assuming that MatchPick is a join record between Match and User and has a `belongs_to` relationship with User)

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks Steve